# What is wrong with using a static member object with a class?

Tags: c++, static

I have heard that using static member objects is not a very good practice.

Say for example, I have this code:

```
class Foo {
...
static MyString str;
};
```

I define and initialize this variable in the implementation file of this class as:

```
MyString Foo::str = "Some String"; // This is fine as my string API handles this.
```

When I run this code, I get a warning:

```
warning:'Foo::str' requires global construction.
```

I have quite much of such members in my class, what is the best way to handle this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the arguments against them are the same as for global variables:

1. Initialization order between different compilation units is undefined.
2. Initialization order inside one compilation unit may affect the behavior — thus non trivial ordering may be required.
3. If a constructor throws an exception you can't catch it, your program is terminated.

APPENDED: To handle this properly you must either make sure that above points don't apply to your code and ignore the warning, or redesign your program: Do you really need them static? Why not use `const char* Foo::str = "Some String";`?

Comment: While I appreciate your list, those are mostly implementation details. From a functional point of view, this also affects reentrance, and thus testability and multithreaded programs.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest reason for concern with this example is that constructing the static member object happens before `main()` and destruction happens after `main()` (or when you call `exit()`).  So far, that's a good thing.  But when you have multiple objects like this in your program, you risk a bug where code attempts to use an object that has not yet been constructed or has already been destroyed.

The C++ FAQ Lite has [some helpful discussion](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14) on this topic, including a workaround/solution.  Recommended reading is questions 10.14 through 10.18.  10.17 is most directly applicable to your example.

Answer (score 2):

Using a static member, you are not guaranteeing thread safety, imagine two threads trying to access the static member - now what would be the value of that member - was it the one from thread x or thread y, this also induces another side-effect, race conditions, where one thread modifies the static member before the other thread completes... in other words, using a static member can be hazardous...

Comment: It's true not only for static members but for any shared data between threads. I think this doesn't answer the question properly as thread safety has nothing to do with static members initialization.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, it is required to know the number of instances of a class. This would require a class static member to track the count of instances.

There is nothing wrong in having a static member of a class if the problem solution requires such a design. It's just that the nitty gritties have to be taken care as mentioned in other posts.